# improve tesseract OCR number recognition

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I've been playing around with tesseract and the different psm options, im trying to work with this pattern:

[image]

When I process this I get 52658, it switches up the 5's and the 8's and losses the decimal place. Is there anyway I could get a more precise reading on this:

The Image was initially transparent i added the white background with PHP to try to give it better recognition, no result.

Comment: You could try to preprocess the image and [erode](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is simply too small.

I resized it using ImageMagick and it started to OCR correctly, with Tesseract both 3.02 and 3.03:

```
$ tesseract 8UAYy.png ooo
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
$ cat ooo.txt 
B2 655

$ convert 8UAYy.png -resize 300% ooo.png
$ tesseract ooo.png ooo
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
$ cat ooo.txt 
82.685

$ tesseract302 ooo.png ooo
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
$ cat ooo.txt 
82.685
```

Comment: Yep I finally got it too using:  `$image->setResolution(150,150);` followed by 
`$image->resampleImage(175,175,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);`

Comment: I also had to use a lot of sharpening after the resize to get it to work